# Как написать SQL запрос для изменения поля date(прибавить один день к дате)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я создал событие в phpMyAdmin, которое должно каждые 24 часа прибавлять +1 день к каждой записи в поле(типа date) *session_date* в таблице *sessions*.
Вот мой SQL запрос: `` UPDATE `sessions` SET `session_date` = DATE_ADD(`session_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) ``
Еще пробовал так: `` UPDATE `sessions` SET `session_date` = DATE_ADD((SELECT `session_date` FROM `sessions`), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ``
Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?(Это мой первый проект)
[image: Для каждого сеанса созданы по два записи, с сегодняшней и завтрашней датой]

Comment: А как вы узнаете прибавляли вы уже сегодня или нет ? Если требуется к каждой записи в БД что то прибавлять по расписанию то вы не правильно используете БД. Для каких целей вам понадобилось это делать ?

Comment: Идея такова: есть сайт для кинотеатра и в бд в таблице sessions хранятся сессии, то есть id фильма, дата сессии(session_date), время и поле json для хранения массива о свободных и занятых местах. Нужно чтобы данные в базе данных автоматический обновлялись каждый день в 00:00, чтобы юзеры могли бронировать места еще за день до сеанса.

Comment: не надо обновлять, надо если нету добавлять запись с датой. тогда билеты можно покупать на несколько дней вперед. А прошедшие дни подчищать

Comment: @splash58 я прикрепил скрин с бд, каким образом можно добавлять записи сохраняя данные из других столбцов(дублировать записи только с +1 днем в дате)?

Comment: сохранять ли данные должно зависеть от другой таблицы - расписания. когда вы ставите фильм в прокат, создавайте сразу таблицу на все сеансы. А продавать можно только на ближайшие несколько дней - на сколько укажите

Comment: А чем вы запускаете выполнение этого запроса?

Comment: @Namerek с помощью event-ов в mysql

Comment: А зачем сохранять данные из из других столбцов ? Если записи за сеанс в нужный день еще нет, то и вроде как никаких данных, которые надо было бы сохранить нет